# How to insert auto generated ID into foreign key column

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I'm quite new to c# and SQL. I have two tables (Project, Proptype). These are what is inside the tables:

**Project**:

- ProjectId (Primary Key, Auto Increment, int)
- PropTypeId (Foreign Key, Auto Increment, int)
- ProjectName
- NumberOfUnits
- Location

**Proptype**:

- PropTypeId (Primary Key, Auto Increment, int)
- PropType

I would put the `PropTypeId` inside a combobox which would display the contents of `Proptype` column (which has been populated with the values `Residential` and `Industrial`).

Here is a screenshot of what the program looks like: [Image of program with error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q79p.jpg)

This is the code that I use:

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(dbconnectionstring);

try
{
    sqlcon.Open();

    SqlCommand createcommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Project](ProjectName, NumberOfUnits, PropTypeId, Location)" +  
      "VALUES(@ProjectName, @NumberOfUnits, @PropTypeId, @Location)", sqlcon);

    createcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", prname.Text);
    createcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfUnits", unitnum.Text);
    createcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropTypeId", prtype.Text);
    createcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", locationtb.Text);

    createcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    sqlcon.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I'm using SQL Server, if that's of any help.

When I run the program, it displays the error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Residential' to data type int.

I expected the code to automatically recognize that 'Residential' has the Id of '1' and would put that into the Project table. I guess that's not the case. Hopefully somebody can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether it is automatically incrementing or not seems irrelevant to your question: it is an automatically incrementing key in a foreign table. It is not automatically incrementing in the table you are inserting to. The issue with your question is that you are trying to pass a C# _string_ where an _int_ is expected.

Comment: I see.  Would it be easier to just change it to the Proptype column instead of Proptype Id?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you'll need the prototype id (as an integer) here. See the linked duplicate or Metal's answer.

Comment: I've tried Metal's answer. It says "No overload for method 'ToInt32' takes 0 arguments". Im going to try and figure out how to incorporate the solution from the linked duplicate next.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this one

```
 createcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropTypeId", prtype.Text);
```

should be

```
 createcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropTypeId", Convert.ToInt32([prtTypeId.Text]));
```